# Can I run openJDK 1.8 alongside sun JDK 1.6?

Tags: java-8, java, java-6, sun

I have openJDK 1.8 installed and I need Sun's JDK 1.6 for a project (I also need Java 8 for my IDE but it cna be either openJDK or Sun's). Do I need to uninstall openJDK or can they exist side by side?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. But `JAVA_HOME` can lead to only one instance (and only one `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` directory should be added to `PATH` env var)

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can install multiple JDKs at a time, yet only one of them may be set as *default java* (`JAVA_HOME`). This would be called if you type `java myProgramName`.

If you want to be sure to run a certain program with a certain JDK, run them with `/full/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java myProgramName`.

Answer (score 0):

They can exists side by side.  Eclipse (for instance) allows you to have multiple VM's installed, and pick between them on a project-by-project basis.  Other IDE's probably have similar capabilities.

[image]

Comment: I know you can run multiple Sun JDK's side by side, but I saw online people having issues running it alongside openJDK.